# gtk/gtk.h not found vscode linux

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Trying to compile a basic hello world for gtk and while vscode does detect gtk and does not underline it like it was, when it goes to compile it comes out with the error.

```
    1 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Did have to correct a includePath to get vscode detecting the package

```
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-linux/include",
                "/usr/include/gtk-3.0",
                "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
                "/usr/include/harfbuzz",
                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
                "/usr/include/atk-1.0"
```

Have tried using vspkg to install gtk

I'm pretty new to C. I understand a bit of the general logic but I'm trying to do a simple breakout game.

[Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOCXp.png)

Comment: The listed include paths are for intellisense. You have to configure your build configuration. How do you build your project?

Comment: There is no such thing like C/C++. Is it C or C++? That are two different languages.

Comment: Using C. Included both because from what I know C programs work on C++ right? Not sure about my build configuration. I'm very new to C. Basically just trying to get it to compile and work.

Comment: _"C programs work on C++"_ Not all C codes are valid C++ codes. Some C features are not allowed in C++. How do you compile your project. Without this information it's not possible to help.

Comment: Currently it is compiling via gcc.

Comment: You have to add the include paths with `-I` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Is there a way to have Vscode automatically do that?

Comment: Yes, there is a build configuration in VSCode. You can add compiler flags like include paths and library paths.

Comment: Thanks for the help!